# How to access temporary table(# table sybase ase 15) from java using mybatis

Tags: java, orm, mybatis, temp-tables, sybase-ase15

I have requirement such as

> follow are the steps

```
step 1 : From java process I will create a temp table(# table ).
step 2 : Insert some data to that temp table(# table ) after parsing a csv file.
Step 3 : Will call a Procedure which will access that temp table(# table ) 
         and do some processing and insert the data from temp table 
         to a parmanent table, and return error if present
Step 4 : Drop the temp table

ORM Tool : mybatis 
Database server : SYBASE ASE 15.0
Programming Language : Java,Tsql
```

Please help

> **EDIT** :  Found out the answer, I have to use global temptable (## temp table) :)

Comment: What have you implemented so far, and what problems are you facing ?

Comment: First of all Is it feasible ? I have done normal java-mybatis table creation (not # table)

Comment: Yes, it's doable. With mybatis, there should be no problem to execute SQL DDL instruction, such as "CREATE TABLE" / "DROP TABLE", to create and delete the temporary table, same when it comes to call stored procedure.

Comment: I am using temp table . creating a temp table in a statement and insert data into that temp table using another statement

Comment: For completeness, Sybase ASE currently does not support global temp tables with the # syntax. That is MS SQL Server syntax. Global temp tables are simply created in tempdb with a normal name without a leading '#'.